# Make page margin count for footnotes and header as well

Tags: header, latex, margin, page-numbering, footnotes

I am using the following page geometry:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report} % A4 paper and 12pt font size
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2.0cm, bottom=1.0cm, left=2.0cm, right=5.0cm, footskip = 1.0cm]{geometry}
```

I need the "white" margins of the page to be exactly like that, meaning that if there is a footnotes, the margin between the footnote end and the end of the page is 1cm. The same counts for the head, except for the page number. So the margin between the top of the page and the first line of text needs to be 2cm. The page number (top) would ideally be centred in that space.

Somehow I currently end up with 2.4cm in the top and less than one at the bottom.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manual for the `geometry` package (http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf, figure 2 p. 3):

> If `includehead` is set to true, headheight and headsep are considered
>   as a part of height. In the same way, `includefoot` takes footskip into
>   height.

So this

```
\usepackage[a4paper, top=2.0cm, bottom=1.0cm, left=2.0cm, right=5.0cm, footskip = 1.0cm, includehead, includefoot]{geometry}
```

should do the trick?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! By using mentioned code, the margins at top and bottom increase tremendously. Is there any kind of default size of footers/headers which I should adjust?

Comment: My bad. Have you tried tweaking headheight, headsep and footskip? Those are probably larger than what you want. (Again, it is useful to refer to the manual to find which argument controls what.)

Comment: \usepackage[a4paper, top=2.0cm, bottom=1.0cm, left=2.0cm, right=5.0cm, includefoot, footskip = 0cm, headheight = 2cm]{geometry}   This somewhat is acceptable, not perfect though since still margin at the bottom varies between a little less and a little more than 1cm, and the same for the top.

Comment: It's bizarre that it doesn't line up. I ran an MWE with `\usepackage{layouts}`, then at the beginning of the document (i.e. after `\begin{document}`), add the lines:

\printinunitsof{mm}{\pagevalues}
\verb|\marginparwidth|: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\marginparwidth}
\pagediagram

This prints the dimensions of your page and text in mm. In my MWE, which only specifies what you've specified in your question, I get `textheight = 266.997 mm` for `paperheight = 296.997 mm`; i.e. to the mm the spacing that you want.